# How to get Miracast working with Sitecom WLA 7100

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, projector, screen-sharing, miracast

I bought a [Sitecom AC1200 / WLA7100 Wifi adapter](https://www.sitecom.com/en/wi-fi-usb-30-adapter-ac1200/wla-7100/p/1617) and a LG 42LB650V TV which supports Miracast so I can share the screen of my PC (running Windows 8.1) on my TV using Miracast. The problem is that the 'add a wireless display' option is missing in Windows.

I tried the following things:

- Removed all other network adapters (virtualbox, hyper-v, etc.).
- Turned on Windows' 'network projection' feature.
- Installed the latest drivers for the Wifi adapter... This doesn't fix the problem and actually results in me not being able to connect to my Wifi network.
- Added my TV as a device using the settings charm, under PC and devices -> devices. Adding the device worked fine, it's now listed under "Play devices" and it says 'Not Windows certified'.

Does anyone know how I can enable Miracast so I can share my desktop on my TV?

Comment: Check this http://digitalmediaphile.com/index.php/2013/07/15/how-to-use-non-certified-play-to-devices-in-windows-8-1/ whether this helps.

Comment: But that's for 'play to' from Store apps? That's not what I want, I want to share my desktop.